# Creating custom item types in beamer lists

Tags: beamer, itemize

I would like to use a syntax like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \pro An advantage
    \con A disadvantage
\end{itemize}
```

Where `\pro` and `\con` replace `\item` and they have the following effect: Color the text on a given color and change the marker type (that can be globaly set with `\setbeamertemplate{itemize}[square]`) to a check-mark or a cross.

Currently I have the following, which works close enough except that I don't know how to change the marker type locally inside the macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\pro}[1]{\item {\color{green}#1}}
\newcommand{\con}[1]{\item {\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{itemize}
            \pro{pro 1}
            \con{con 1}
            \begin{itemize}
                    \pro{pro in subitem}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

The behavior of the macro should be the same within subitems.

Comment: You  can just use the optional argument of `\item` e.g. `\item[\crosscommand]\color{...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\item[]` to set the marker. For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\pro}[1]{\item[\ding{52}] {\color{green}#1}}
\newcommand{\con}[1]{\item[\ding{56}] {\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{itemize}
            \pro{pro 1}
            \con{con 1}
            \begin{itemize}
                    \pro{pro in subitem}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: ticks and crosses]

Comment: Nice. It also allows to change the color of  the mark, e.g., `\newcommand{\pro}[1]{\color{green}\item[\ding{52}] {\color{green}#1}}`

Comment: @jsb Thanks. Yes, though the question explicitly specified applying the colour only to the following text, so I didn't do that here.

Comment: How difficult would it be to get a syntax of the form `\pro content` instead of `\pro{content}`? This is simply out of curiosity, the current solution is sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: @jsb Without the coloured `content`, easy. With the coloured `content`, hard. Also, high cost in terms of side-effects and complications. You could say `\color{green}` and leave it open, but you'd need to know it would get changed again by something else (another `\item`? `\end{itemize}`?), so you'd need to know what colour to change it back to, as well, which is not so straightforward in `beamer`.

Comment: @jsb You *might* be able to piggy-back on something `beamer` already does. The way it works for `\item<alert>`, for example. So maybe it would be more doable in `beamer` than elsewhere, after all. But I don't know how much of the `alert` apparatus you'd have to duplicate. You could change the `alert` colour and use that. That would be easy, but you'd have to never want to see `alert`ed text in the scope of the `\item`.

Comment: And you'd still have to change it back, I guess ...

Comment: I am actually using it without the colored content, and just coloring the tick mark. Also, there is a noticeable issue with the current approach, it does not inherit the font size of the frame. So if I use \small then the text within \pro{} will be much larger.

Comment: @jsb I can't reproduce the sizing issue. If I use `\tiny` at the start of the frame, everything is very small, including the text within `\pro`. The text within `\pro` when used as a sub-item is then larger, but that has nothing to do with `\pro`. You get the same effect with an ordinary `\item`. That's just a feature of how `beamer` does things.

Comment: @jsb That is, sub-items don't 'inherit the font size of the frame' regardless because the fonts are set with `beamer` templates and font standardly changes for sub-items.